# Exporting data from text file to gridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gridview, export

I'm trying to export data from text file to gridview in c#. the text files containing only numbers.
text file format
1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 8786868, ......

i need to set the table column to 10 then new row till the numbers in the text file finished.
Thanks.

Comment: Import the file as a single string using a reader, .Split(',') the string, parse the resulting array and create a way to get it into a DataTable. use the DataTable as the source for the GridView and bind it.  Do you an example of something you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't your homework.  If it is, please make it your duty to improve this somewhat kludgy code.  You will also have to use System.IO to read in the file and get it into the string.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNumbers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
var dt = new DataTable();
string fileText = "1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 8786868,1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 8786868,1313232 , 10, 7676768, 8786868,1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 8786868,1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 20,1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 8786868,1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 8786868,1313232 , 12323232, 7676768, 8786868,";
string[] nums = fileText.Split(',');
//set up columns
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("Col" + i, typeof(int)); //add integer columns and name them
}
int colCount = 0;
int[] oneRow = new int[10];
int n, failCount = 0;
foreach (string s in nums)
{
    if (int.TryParse(s, out n))
    {
        oneRow[colCount] = n;
        colCount++;
    }
    else  //invalid integer
    {
        failCount++;  //you could use this value if you want to see if the file was fully valid or not.
    }
    //check if row is complete
    if (colCount == 10)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(oneRow[0], oneRow[1], oneRow[2], oneRow[3], oneRow[4], oneRow[5], oneRow[6], oneRow[7], oneRow[8], oneRow[9]);
        colCount = 0;
        oneRow = new int[10]; //reset array
    }
}
if (colCount > 0) dt.Rows.Add(oneRow[0], oneRow[1], oneRow[2], oneRow[3], oneRow[4], oneRow[5], oneRow[6], oneRow[7], oneRow[8], oneRow[9]); //add final incomplete row

//reference the DataTable as a source to the GridView and bind it.
gvNumbers.DataSource = dt;
gvNumbers.DataBind();
```